# Правда ли что .NET Framework устарел?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Правда ли что .NET Framework устарел? очень часто слышу это, но подтверждения нигде не находи и если он правда устарел, то что сейчас учить?

Comment: «что сейчас учить?» — .NET 5 и новее (на момент написания этого комментария [последняя версия — .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8))

Comment: Устарел он в основном в том смысле, что `.NET Framework` жёстко привязан к `Windows`, а более новые версии `.NET Core` (и далее просто `.NET`) работают одинаково успешно и на `Windows` и на `Linux`, поэтому за ними будущее.

Comment: то есть надо просто учить более новые версии .NET и .Net Core?

Comment: Был .NET Framework, затем Microsoft решила пойти на другие OS, создала в 19 году ответвление, назвала .NET Core, выпустила 3 его версии и в конце 22 года поняла, что бессмысленно делать 2 разных ответвления, когда можно все это объединить. В итоге, в мае 2022 был выпущен .NET 5, который Microsoft написали с нуля и в который перенести почти все из .NET Framework и .NET Core, получили в итоге тот-же .NET Framework на стероидах, оптимизированный, и поддерживающий разные OS. Так что да, "устарел", примерно на 11 версий. Так что, хотите новое, новые фишки языка, изучайте всегда новое, а это .NET.

Comment: то есть .NET 8 это продолжение .NET 5?

Comment: Да, это его новая версия. Список всех релизов, с датами выхода и когда были завершены можете глянуть на [офф сайте](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet), правда без .NET Framework.

Comment: спасибо большое!